# Source Tree Authentication Error

Tags: git, authentication, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to do a pull from SourceTree, but I keep getting this authentication error.

I've set up my GitHub account, and I don't get why it's a problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled 2FA you have to provided a personal access token instead of entering your password for HTTPS ([see link](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended))